# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in AsyncTask on API 16 to 19

Tags: android, android-asynctask, noclassdeffounderror

I have an error that only happens in android 4 (API 16 to 19).

I use the following code

```
private class AcceptBooking extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    int response;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        switch (response){
            case NO_UPDATE:
                startApp();
                break;
            case SUGEST_UPDATE:
                adviceUpdate();
                break;
            case FORCE_UPDATE:
                forceUpdate();
                break;
            default:
                startApp();
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        response = DBConnect.updateApp();

        return "done";
    }
}
```

And when I try to execute this AsyncTask I get the following error:

```
com.socialcar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/socialcar/api_connection/DBConnect
    at com.socialcar.SplashScreenActivity$AcceptBooking.doInBackground(SplashScreenActivity.java:154)
    at com.socialcar.SplashScreenActivity$AcceptBooking.doInBackground(SplashScreenActivity.java:126)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.socialcar.api_connection.DBConnect
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at com.socialcar.SplashScreenActivity$AcceptBooking.doInBackground(SplashScreenActivity.java:154) 
    at com.socialcar.SplashScreenActivity$AcceptBooking.doInBackground(SplashScreenActivity.java:126) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

And this is the dependencies that I have in gradle:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
```

I try to find a solution in this and other forums and apparently the com.android.support:appcompat-v7 version can be the problem but changing that won´t work. And Also I java.util.objects is introduced in Java 7 and that this also can affect but I not sure what to do to fix this.

Any other idea will be welcome.

**EDIT**

Here is the BDConnect class that is giving the error:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.os.Build;

import com.socialcar.BuildConfig;
import com.socialcar.Config;
import com.socialcar.booking.NavigationActivity;
import com.socialcar.custom.SHA1;
import com.socialcar.http.RequestMethod;
import com.socialcar.http.RestClient;
import com.socialcar.model.Booking;
import com.socialcar.model.BookingList;
import com.socialcar.model.LoginResult;
import com.socialcar.model.Token;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by PcCom1 on 14/03/2016.
 */
public class DBConnect {
    private static String URL = "https://someurl.com/";
    private static String SOCIAL_CAR_URL_OAUTH = URL + "test/auth";
    private static String SOCIAL_CAR_URL = URL + "test";
    private static String SOCIAL_CAR_URL_NO_V1 = URL + "test";
    private static String SOCIAL_CAR_URL_LOGIN = URL + "test/login";


    private static void checkResponseCode(RestClient restClient) throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
        int responseCode = restClient.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == 500 || responseCode == 503) {
            // ERRO no servidor
        } else if (responseCode == 404) {
            // ERRO pagina nao encontrada
        } else if (responseCode == 401) {
            if (restClient.getResponse().contains("Invalid JWT")){
                throw new IOException("JWT");
            }
        } else if (responseCode != 200) {
            // ERRO se a resposta n?o for a correta
            throw new IOException();
        }

    }

    public static int updateApp(){
        String response = "";
        try {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(SOCIAL_CAR_URL+"/mobile/updates");
            String model = Build.MODEL;
            int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("mobile", model);
            data.put("sdk-version", version);
            data.put("version-code", versionCode);
            restClient.setJsonObject(data);
            restClient.execute(RequestMethod.POST);
            checkResponseCode(restClient);
            response = restClient.getResponse();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            return jsonObject.getInt("update");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static Token refreshToken(String refreshToken){
        String response = "";
        Token token = new Token();
        try {
            //password = SHA1.toSHA1(password);
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(SOCIAL_CAR_URL_NO_V1+"/token-refresh");
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("_token", refreshToken);
            restClient.setJsonObject(data);
            restClient.execute(RequestMethod.POST);
            checkResponseCode(restClient);
            response = restClient.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Error de conexión
            return null;
        }
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            token.setToken(jsonObject.getString("token"));
            token.setRefreshToken(jsonObject.getString("refresh_token"));
            return token;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //error desconocido de parseo
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static int logout(String email, String registration_id, String token){
        String response = "";
        try {
            //password = SHA1.toSHA1(password);
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(SOCIAL_CAR_URL_OAUTH+"/user/logouts", token, null);
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("_username", email);
            data.put("device_token", registration_id);
            restClient.setJsonObject(data);
            restClient.execute(RequestMethod.POST_TOKEN);
            checkResponseCode(restClient);
            response = restClient.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Error de conexión
            return -999;
        }
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            return jsonObject.getInt("error");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //error desconocido de parseo
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1000;
        }
    }

    public static Token login(String email, String password){
        String response = "";
        Token token = new Token();
        try {
            //password = SHA1.toSHA1(password);
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(SOCIAL_CAR_URL_NO_V1+"/login-check");
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("_username", email);
            data.put("_password", password);
            restClient.setJsonObject(data);
            restClient.execute(RequestMethod.POST);
            checkResponseCode(restClient);
            response = restClient.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Error de conexión
            return null;
        }
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            token.setToken(jsonObject.getString("token"));
            if(jsonObject.has("refresh_token"))
                token.setRefreshToken(jsonObject.getString("refresh_token"));
            return token;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //error desconocido de parseo
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static LoginResult getUserInfo(String regId, Token token){
        String response = "";
        LoginResult loginResult;
        try {

            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(
                    SOCIAL_CAR_URL_OAUTH+"/user/info?device_token=" + regId,
                    token.getToken(), null);
            restClient.execute(RequestMethod.GET_TOKEN);
            checkResponseCode(restClient);
            response = restClient.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            loginResult = new LoginResult();
            // Error de conexión
            loginResult.setError(999);
            return loginResult;
        }
        try {

            loginResult  = JSONParser.getLoginResultFromJson(response);


            return loginResult;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //error desconocido de parseo
            e.printStackTrace();
            loginResult = new LoginResult();
            loginResult.setError(1000);
            return loginResult;
        }
    }

    public static Token loginFacebook(String facebookId, String facebookToken, String email, String regId){
        String response = "";
        Token token = new Token();
        try {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(SOCIAL_CAR_URL_LOGIN+"/facebooks", null, facebookId);
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("email", email);
            data.put("facebook_id", facebookId);
            data.put("token-facebook", facebookToken);
            restClient.setJsonObject(data);
            restClient.execute(RequestMethod.POST_OAUTH);
            checkResponseCode(restClient);
            response = restClient.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jsonObject.has("token")){
                token.setToken(jsonObject.getString("token"));
                token.setRefreshToken(jsonObject.getString("refresh_token"));
                token.setError(0);
                return token;
            }
            token.setError(jsonObject.getInt("error"));
            return token;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            //error desconocido de parseo
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static Token loginGooglePlus(String googleId, String googleToken, String email, String regId){
        String response = "";
        Token token = new Token();
        try {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(SOCIAL_CAR_URL_LOGIN+"/googles", null, googleId);
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("email", email);
            data.put("google_id", googleId);
            data.put("token_google", googleToken);
            restClient.setJsonObject(data);
            restClient.execute(RequestMethod.POST_OAUTH);
            checkResponseCode(restClient);
            response = restClient.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jsonObject.has("token")){
                token.setToken(jsonObject.getString("token"));
                token.setRefreshToken(jsonObject.getString("refresh_token"));
                token.setError(0);
                return token;
            }
            token.setError(jsonObject.getInt("error"));
            return token;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //error desconocido de parseo
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static BookingList getPendingBookingList(int ownerId, String token){
        String response = "";
        BookingList bookingList;
        try {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(SOCIAL_CAR_URL_OAUTH+"/booking/pendings/"+ownerId, token, null);
            restClient.execute(RequestMethod.GET_TOKEN);
            checkResponseCode(restClient);
            response = restClient.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(e.getMessage() == "JWT"){
                bookingList = new BookingList();
                // Error de conexión
                bookingList.setError(Config.JWT_EXPIRED);
                bookingList.setBookings(new ArrayList<Booking>());
                return bookingList;
            }
            bookingList = new BookingList();
            // Error de conexión
            bookingList.setError(999);
            bookingList.setBookings(new ArrayList<Booking>());
            return bookingList;
        }
        try {

            bookingList  = JSONParser.getBookingListFromJson(response);
            return bookingList;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //error desconocido de parseo
            e.printStackTrace();
            bookingList = new BookingList();
            bookingList.setError(1000);
            bookingList.setBookings(new ArrayList<Booking>());
            return bookingList;
        }
    }

    public static Booking getBookingDetailsOwner(int booking_line, String token){
        String response = "";
        Booking booking;
        try {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(SOCIAL_CAR_URL_OAUTH+"/booking/owner_details/"+booking_line, token, null);
            restClient.execute(RequestMethod.GET_TOKEN);
            checkResponseCode(restClient);
            response = restClient.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(e.getMessage() == "JWT"){
                booking = new Booking();
                // Error de conexión
                booking.setError(Config.JWT_EXPIRED);
                return booking;
            }
            booking = new Booking();
            // Error de conexión
            booking.setError(999);
            return booking;
        }
        try {

            booking  = JSONParser.getBookingFromJson(response);


            return booking;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //error desconocido de parseo
            e.printStackTrace();
            booking = new Booking();
            //loginResult.setError(1000);
            return booking;
        }
    }

    public static int cancelBookingByOwner(int booking_line, String reason, String description, String token){
        String response = "";
        try {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(SOCIAL_CAR_URL_OAUTH+"/booking/cancels/"+booking_line, token, null);
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("reason", reason);
            data.put("reason_description", description);
            restClient.setJsonObject(data);
            restClient.execute(RequestMethod.POST_TOKEN);
            checkResponseCode(restClient);
            response = restClient.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(e.getMessage() == "JWT") {
                return Config.JWT_EXPIRED;
            }
            // Error de conexión
            return 999;
        }
        try {

            int error  = JSONParser.getErrorResultFromJson(response);


            return error;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //error desconocido de parseo
            e.printStackTrace();
            //loginResult.setError(1000);
            return 1000;
        }
    }

    public static int acceptBookingByOwner(int booking_line, String token){
        String response = "";
        try {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(SOCIAL_CAR_URL_OAUTH+"/booking/accepts/"+booking_line, token, null);
            restClient.execute(RequestMethod.GET_TOKEN);
            checkResponseCode(restClient);
            response = restClient.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Error de conexión
            return 999;
        }
        try {
            int error  = JSONParser.getErrorResultFromJson(response);
            return error;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //error desconocido de parseo
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(e.getMessage() == "JWT") {
                return Config.JWT_EXPIRED;
            }
            //loginResult.setError(1000);
            return 1000;
        }
    }

}
```

and the gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.socialcar"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 33
        versionName "3.0.1"
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // will not include LICENSE file
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:17.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
}
```

Manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".booking.NavigationActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_booking"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.socialcar.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.socialcar"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.socialcar.gcm.GcmMessageHandler"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```

Comment: it seems that the problem is from your DBConnect class! have you define it correctly?

Comment: set replace return "done" to return null

Comment: the error suggests it is unable to find your "DBConnect" Class. If it is defined properly, try clean and rebuilding the app.

Comment: Yes I define it correctly and I tried already to clean and rebuild. Actually it is working properly if you use API 20 and beyond. And it even doesn't reach the return. It breaks just in the line ´response = DBConnect.updateApp();´ I try to debug it and it even doesn't enter to the class (obvious because as the error says it cannot be found).

Comment: @Iban Arriola : your 'DBConnect' class is from your package or from library?

Comment: DBConnect Is from my package

Comment: I have another tip... if I use DBConnect out of the AsyncTask it works but if I use it in the AsyncTask it won't work. The problem is that I am using an API to get some data and I need to put it into an AsyncTask

Comment: @Iban Arriola please post your 'DBConnect ' class code if it is possible.

Comment: I just edit the post with DBConnect class

Comment: Is your multidexEnabled true in gradle? @IbanArriola

Comment: Yes. I added the gradle too so you can check it

Comment: I'm asking do you have this line `multiDexEnabled true` anywhere in the gradle? @IbanArriola

Comment: Yes it is into defaultConfig

Comment: In your manifest which application tag are you using? @IbanArriola

Comment: @Iban Arriola  as you said that your DBConnect.updateApp(); work out of async. i hope that the problem could be from this line in your DBConnect.updateApp() function :restClient.execute(RequestMethod.POST);. you can comment all of your code in .updateApp() function and start to uncomment them line by line and run your code and find out that witch line of function cause exception.

Comment: @pooyan out of async where it fails is when I try to connect to the API because it has to be done in an AsyncTask and if I put it inside async it won't enter in the updateApp() function it just fails in the moment that I call DBConnect.

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty I just put the manifest with everything that is inside application.

Comment: Add this line in gradle: `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` Now, inside your mainfest add this line, `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`. Then create the following class: `public class MultiDexApplication extends Application {
    public MultiDexApplication() {
    }

    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}` @IbanArriola

Comment: Great now it is working! Thank you. Just put it as answer to put it as write answer.

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty please put this as answer so I can check as right answer. Otherwise I will do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line in build.gradle:

`compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

Now, inside the application tag in your mainfest add this line,

`android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`

Then create the following class:

```
public class MultiDexApplication extends Application { 
public MultiDexApplication() { } 
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {   super.attachBaseContext(base); 
MultiDex.install(this);
} 
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me, but its not explained well. Add the first line inside `dependencies` under `build.gradle`. Add the second line inside the `application` tag under `AndroidManifest`. Finally just create a class as its defined.

Comment: I have added those things in the answer. Thanks @0014